# neither nth-child nor nth-of-type

Tags: css

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="chat-area">
  <div class="username-area">
  </div>
  <div class="message-area">
  </div>
  <div class="options-area">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="chat-area">
  <div class="username-area">
  </div>
  <div class="message-area">
  </div>
  <div class="options-area">
  </div>
</div>
```

And I'm trying to alternate the background colours of `username-area` between `#00A6FF` and `#27FF00`. In my css I have:

```
.chat-area .username-area:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #00A6FF;
}

.chat-area .username-area:nth-child(even){
  background-color: #27FF00;
}
```

But all the `username-area` divs are being set to `#00A6FF`. I tried using  `:nth-of-type` and I've also tried using expressions (`2n+1` and `2n+2`) instead of 'odd' and 'even' but I'm having no luck figuring this out. I had a look at a few questions on this site but the solutions haven't helped or seem to be addressing issues that don't apply to my code, I think.

Comment: Because they are the first `div` (its type) and first child under each parent. So obviously only the `odd` selector will get applied. CSS selectors will not work across parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give a turn to the ommelete :)

```
.chat-area:nth-child(odd) .username-area{
  background-color: #00A6FF;
}

.chat-area:nth-child(even) .username-area{
  background-color: #27FF00;
}
```

It's because the odd and even elements are `.chat-area`, not `username-area`.

Comment: Ah! Silly me! Yes this works perfectly and I'll accept your answer as soon as SO lets me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just so that one:

```
   .chat-area:nth-child(odd) .username-area{
      background-color: #00A6FF;
    }

    .chat-area:nth-child(even) .username-area{
      background-color: #27FF00;
    }
```

@Marcos Pérez Gude was faster :)

Comment: Thanks :) This is very kind and a warm welcome for me :)